# Default Language setting in front end not working in Joomla 1.5

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, redirect

In my site there are 3 Languages (Arabic, English, Netherlands). I am using Joomfish to manage translation. My client asked me that he want Arabic as his default language. That is www.mysite.com should be load in Arabic. I already made Arabic as the default language from Joomla admin panel. But the site is still loading in English. What to do.?

*Tip found myself : Actually the Arabic site will be loaded by opening www.mysite.com/ar. So i tried to do a htaccess redirection. Unfortunately that too didn't worked.*

Kindly share your ideas to get ride of this situation.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday for a spanish/english website where Spanish was to be the default. It was driving me crazy!!!! Anyway, the solution is to go to Plugin Manager and select the Jfrouter system plugin.

On the right hand side change the "Language selection for new visitors?" setting to "site default language" instead of "browser settings". It turns out that the Joomfish plugin was using the language of my browser instead of the site default.

Comment: Another way i found my self is just set a URL redirection from C-Panel. ie, Actually if we need Arabic, we can access Arabic site through going to the URL www.mysite.com/ar. Thats it. I simply fixed a URL Redirection in C-Panel from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/ar. But yours sounds more good. Thanks for the help. :)